# How can I save a g-botorch model to my mlflow artifact store in s3 and register the model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pytorch, mlflow

I'm trying to save a model to my mlflow tracking server with the following code:

```
mlflow.pytorch.log_model(
            pytorch_model=model,
            artifact_path=f"{mlflow.get_artifact_uri()}/models/g-botorch-model-1",
            #signature=signature,
            registered_model_name="g-botorch-model",
        )
```

The model is of type MultitaskGPyBoTorchModel, and I've made sure that the wrapper class inherits from torch.nn.module. I've configured the mlflow tracking server url and have verified that I'm capable of saving metrics and configuration parameters to the backend store in s3, but when I try to log and register the model with the above code I get the following error:

```
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/registered-models/create failed with error code 404 != 200. Response body: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

The get_artifact_uri() method provides the path to the "artifacts" directory in s3, so I thought it made sense to save the model there. I'm not sure what the artifact_path paremeter needs to point to, and I haven't found any documentation that explains it properly. Do I have to log the model first at a specific location, then register it afterwards by specifying this location?

Any help would be much appreciated.